# How to get the difference in time between NSDate and current time?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a server with objects that each have a created at date. I would like to display my objects in a table view with each cell having a label that tells how many minutes or hours have passed since the object was created, quite like the Facebook or Instagram apps. The server created at date is an NSDate, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you checked ANY of the documentation for NSDate, NSCalendar, and/or NSDateComponents?  (Do you even know how to find the documentation?)

Comment: `double negativeSecondsDifference = [createdDate timeIntervalSinceNow];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the time difference in seconds of two `NSDate` objects like this:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
```

There is a really handy category for `NSDate` from Kevin Lawler. You can get the 'time ago' just by calling:

```
NSDate *date = ... //get date from server
NSString *time = [date timeAgo];
```

You can download the category from github [here](https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo)

Comment: why was my answer down voted? can you please explain

Comment: I'd like to counter this with [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit), made by one of my NSHeroes, Mattt Thompson (author of NSHipster). They're both Cocoapods, so it doesn't really matter either way.